# Python 3 read file by part

Tags: python

I am trying to create a script to read my routes.php file and get the data.

For example I have a routes.php with the ff. data:

```
/**
 * @param string username   required 
 * @param string password   required
 * @param string first_name required
 * @param string last_name  required
 * @param string email      required
 */
Route::POST('/register', 'UserController@Register');

/**
 * @param string username   required 
 * @param string password   required
 * @param string first_name required
 * @param string last_name  required
 * @param string email      required
 */
Route::POST('/login', 'UserController@login');
```

Lets just assume that both of them are different routes.

Now I want to get each routes starting from `/**` to `);`

With the example it returns 2 routes, I just need to get the route url, method, and parameters by using functions I already have.

The only problem is how to read the file per route?

```
# read troutes.php
routes = open('troutes.php', 'r')

# do stuff to each routes
print(routes.read())

# close troutes.php
routes.close()
```

---

**update**

I tried reading the file by line but the problem is how to get the comment above the route and associate it with the route.

```
for line in open('routes.php'):
    li = line.strip()
    if li.startswith('Route::'):

    # print method
    method = find_between( li, "Route::", "(" )
```

---

**update**

python should return 2 routes like this:

```
Method: POST
Url: /register
Parameter:
     username
        type: string
        required: True
     password
        type: string
        required: True

Method: POST
Url: /login
......so on per route
```

Comment: No, I am not working with both. I am just making a script to parse data from a php file. Well just disregard what file I'm parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

routes = []
with open('routes.php', 'r') as f:
    current_comment = ''
    in_comment = False
    for line in f:
        line = line.lstrip()
        if line.startswith('/**'):
            in_comment = True

        if in_comment:
            current_comment += line

        if line.startswith('*/'):
            in_comment = False

        if line.startswith('Route::'):
            matches = re.search(r"Route::([A-Z]+)\('(.*)', '(.*)'\);", line)
            groups = matches.groups()
            routes.append({
                'comment': current_comment,
                'method': groups[0],
                'path': groups[1],
                'handler': groups[2],
            });
            current_comment = '' # reset the comment

print(routes)
```

Output is:

```
[
    {
        'comment': '/**\n* @param string username   required \n* @param string password   required\n* @param string first_name required\n* @param string last_name  required\n* @param string email      required\n*/\n',
        'path': '/register',
        'handler': 'UserController@Register',
        'method': 'POST'
    },
    {
        'comment': '/**\n* @param string username   required \n* @param string password   required\n* @param string first_name required\n* @param string last_name  required\n* @param string email      required\n*/\n',
        'path': '/login',
        'handler': 'UserController@login',
        'method': 'POST'
    }
]
```

So based on your second edit, you still need to parse the comments, to extract the required infos. But this should not be too complicated adapting this script.

Comment: I am also currently trying this. But the `cmd` of windows is very cluttered in running the script. let me find a way to better see is getting returned

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("input") as fd:
    data = [i.strip() for i in fd]

D = []
tmp = []
for i in data:
    tmp.append(i)
    if ';' in i:
        D.append(tmp)
        tmp = []

print D[0][-1]
print D[1][-1]
```

Output:

```
Route::POST('/register', 'UserController@Register');
Route::POST('/login', 'UserController@login');
```

Comment: But I also want to associate the route with its comment. Because I will also parse the parameters for the route from the comment. 

I already tried this with `if line.startswith('Route::'):` But its not what I wanted.

Comment: `D[n]` contains the complete route, the `[-1]` just displays the last entry in the list which is the "Route::" part.

Comment: I see, I tried it but the first list includes `<?php` of the file. It seems like the code delimits it with the `;` ? I am trying with `for routes in D:
  for route in routes:
    print(route)`

Comment: well, your example text in the question didn't include that. Just skip  reading that line then, `if 'php' in line: pass`